# Send page refrence on the second page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have three different web pages with different URLs having the same menu handled from the backed in Wordpress.

I want to send a page reference of the previous page to the next page and customize that page according to the response from the previous page.

Comment: What is the question you are asking? Is it how to send the page references?

Comment: like appending parameters to the anchor tag

Comment: you can use the Referer `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Otherwise you can store the current page in the session or you can add these on your POST or GET request. Pls specific your Question.

Comment: i am using wordpress menu and i am wanted to append parameters with the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Refer this link,
https://coderwall.com/p/xxguoq

Option 2:

Or else you come use custom menu links from wordpress admin panel.(Appearance >  Menus > Choose links and add link to menu)

Hope this helps you.